# GeoPandas installation problems

Tags: python, geopandas, installation, pandas, anaconda

I wanted to install GeoPandas, but I end up getting only this. `(conda install geopandas)`

[image]

I also tried the other methods (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html), but doesn't work either. Can anyone tell me what else I can try or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you check if it is installed by typing `python -c "import geopandas"`

Comment: Pictures of text aren't legible on all devices, and effectively hide the error messages from others who might have the same problem, which is essentially the opposite of the purpose of StackExchange. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact software and the  resulting error messages.

Comment: @AmanBagrecha Yes, this is what i get " File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'"

Comment: Try `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a couple of hours trying to install geopandas myself I came up with those simple command lines that eventually worked for me (geopandas seemed to be incompatible with my initial python 3.10 environement so I created a new one with python 3.8)

In anaconda prompt run those lines:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels defaults

conda create --name name_of_your_environement python=3.8 

conda activate name_of_your_environement

conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```